# Позиционирование элементов на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть такой порядок элементов в html-коде:

```
<aside class="leftaside"></aside>
<aside class="mainaside"></aside>
<section class="mainsection></section>
<aside class="rightaside"></aside>
```

На большом екране елементы позиционируются правильно, как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении разрешения (увеличения mainaside и mainsection ширины на 100%) левый и правый aside убрался, mainsection шла первой и только за ней mainaside?

Comment: Копайте в сторону CSS media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так при помощи flex'ов это можно легко разрулить (если я правильно понял сетку):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 100px;
  background: #39A2AE;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}
.fbox {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.leftaside, .rightaside, .mainaside {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainsection {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftaside, .rightaside {
    display: none;
  }
  .fbox {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .fbox > * {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mainsection {
    order: 1;
  }
  .mainaside {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fbox">
<aside class="leftaside">
left side
</aside>
<aside class="mainaside">
mainaside
</aside>
<section class="mainsection">
  mainsection
</section>
<aside class="rightaside">
rightaside
</aside>
  </div>
```

Comment: mainsection тоже блоком идет, будет ли работать данный код ?

Comment: Что сейчас не соответствует ожидаемому результату?

Comment: В какой-то момент между mainsection и mainaside экран делится пополам, а мне нужно чтобы строго сначала секция, потом aside

Comment: Все, все получилось, спасибо большое! )